# I keep blowing my SSR. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: relay, dc, circuit-design, solid-state-relay

this is my first post. I'm having a real pain trying to get these little **solid state relays** to work for me. 
This is a **DC/DC** relay.

http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=84134870virtualkey59640000virtualkey874-84134870

I have now blown 2 and theyre 75 bucks a pop and I reallllllly dont intend to blow another. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. My circuit seems to follow the data sheet, and in fact, the **relay works for an operation or two**, but after a while, **the things latch shut and go completely kaput** as far as I can tell. The **indicator light still works normally** when I open and close the control switch but regardless, the main line stays latched and I've verified that it remains latched even when completely removed from the circuit.

I'm using appropriate precautions, I even have a **30A fuse** in series and the **relay itself is rated at 30A!** The data suggests a diode but my loads are DC only so I'm not sure it's necessary. Some insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Additionally, does anyone have a better solution than expensive SSR's to this problem? I **need to switch a 36V power supply at roughly 20A continuous** power. This is for an EV so power efficiency is a concern and so is space. Obviously my plan to use SSR's hasnt been working great so far. Here's an image of my circuit side-by-side the data sheet suggested circuit.

**THIS RELAY IS DCDC**

Thanks so much for the help! [image]

Comment: Isnt *Control Voltage* 32Vmax? You are putting 36V into it?

Comment: My multimeter verifies only 5.5VDC across the control terminals. Regardless, the control side isnt causing me any trouble. It's the switching side thats latching closed.

Comment: The control turn-n voltage is 3V. Why would someone drive a 3V circuit with 36V?

Comment: I notice your pin 3 and 4 are swapped in the left drawing.

Comment: Yeah the lower terminals are labeled in reverse but those are the correct voltage polarities and wiring

Comment: Maybe you should disclose the power rating of your "load" then?

Comment: The purpose isnt to drive a 36V circuit from a lower voltage. The purpose is to allow a typical switch to control 36V. So it's necessary to drop the voltage down and use the relay as shown

Comment: The load is a brushless DC motor controller. The rated load is 30A

Comment: If the voltage at the terminals is 5.5V, then the voltage at the resistor is 30.5V, which indicates about 60mA at the input, far more than the 15mA max stated on the datasheet. So I wouldn't discard a problem at the control side yet.

Comment: You should use a diode, even with a DC load. If it is inductive a transient can be developed.

Comment: Actually, the device does have the protective diode. However, at rated load of 30A, how high could be the start-up transient?

Comment: What would be the appropriate way to drop the voltage to the controller? I've tried a voltage divider, with several resistor voltages, r1==r2, and I was getting ridiculously low voltages for anything above 1Kohm. like 1VDC using 2 equal resistors!

Comment: Now's a good time to confess that I am definitely not an EE

Comment: My guess would be that if you have a 30A motor to drive, the controller should be powered all-time, and there should be a low-voltage control signal that starts and stops the motor.

Comment: The motor controller should be handling that.I have no direct connection between this circuit and the motor. I simply provide power, and the controller handles the controls from the throttle, including starting and stoping the motor

Comment: Another consideration is heat. From the data sheet, with no heatsink the SSR is only good for 15 A. This assumes an ambient temperature of 40 C or less, and presumably free airflow. If you have it tucked away in an enclosed area with no cooling (and maybe higher temperature from your controller or converter waste heat) the allowable current will be even less.  Once you get it to stop dying in the short term, you need to look to the long term, and not cooking it in its own juices is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your 1st problem is IN current is 15 mA absolute max while 11mA min.
The actual input is a 1V IR diode opto coupler

Therefore use 13mA or 36V/13mA= 2.78k or closest value

The second is the surge current on a 30A motor can be 8x or more rated current appears to exceed max load current.

Comment: Okay thanks for walking me through the calculation! So as far surge protection is there anything I can really do? Or am I screwed here?

Comment: You are screwed unless you add a softstart PWM control

Comment: I would suggest you buy a cheap 50A PWM motor controller

Comment: This SSR is the wrong solution

Comment: Even a knife switch would be better

Comment: I already have a motor controller that does use PWM. This is the circuit powering that controller

Comment: so that's not enough? what is start time?

Comment: Well something is not enough. I dont think the over current on the control side is the root of this problem. It is a problem I need to fix, but I dont think it could cause the switching side to latch. The two circuits are electrically independent. The relay is switched with an internal photodiode circuit and so nothing I could be feeding the control input could latch the switch.

Comment: ok that's another new input.. surge current is blowing your FET into Shortcircuit failure mode assuming (there aren't) any other new issues( that you forgot to mention)

Comment: oh the diode has to be >30A rating too

Comment: So when you switch off the SSR if the diode is not rated to take over the motor surge current kick back, the MO.sFEt blows from over voltage by lack of protection

Comment: It's not a new input, thats just info from the data sheet I provided. But Ill try the 30A diode and the 2.8K resistor. That seems like a feasible solution to this. Thanks again!

Comment: good luck @NikMelton

Comment: your question shud state 1) diode part number 2) two SSR  's failed in latched On mode 3) the load is a 30A rated BLDC motor with datasheet ..nite

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 It'd probably be possible to use a mosfet inrush current control circuit as well to limit the start current. But that might not let the motor start.